Choose between extras of the same dependency with Poetry
I have a Python project managed with Poetry.
I want to install either psycopg[binary] or psycopg[c] via
$ poetry install -E pgbinary

or
$ poetry install -E pgc

These extras should be mutually exclusive, i.e.
$ poetry install -E pgbinary -E pgc

should raise an error.
This is what I wrote in the pyproject.toml:
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
...
psycopg = { version = "^3.1.0", extras = ["binary", "c"],  optional = true}


[tool.poetry.extras]
pgbinary = ["psycopg[binary]"]
pgc = ["psycopg[c]"]

But when I do one of the following
$ poetry install
$ poetry install -E pgbinay
$ poetry install -E pgc

I always get this
The Poetry configuration is invalid:
  - data.extras.pgbinary[0] must match pattern ^[a-zA-Z-_.0-9]+$

The problem seems related to the square brackets in psycopg[binary] (or psycopg[c]).
Is there a way to choose which extra to install for a specific library during the poetry install?

UPDATE
I've solved with this for now
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
...
psycopg = {version = "^3.1.9", optional=true}
psycopg-binary = {version = "^3.1.9", optional=true}
psycopg-c = {version = "^3.1.9", optional=true}

[tool.poetry.extras]
pgbinary = ["psycopg", "psycopg-binary"]
pgc = ["psycopg", "psycopg-c"]

It works, but has stated here
You shouldn’t install this package directly: use instead

pip install "psycopg[c]"

to install a version of the optimization package matching the psycopg version installed.

If there is a way to write version = "^3.1.9" just once, it would be great.
Moreover, the extras are still not mutually exclusive.

Post your solution as an answer, not as an extended update to the question!

Why should psycopg[c] and psycopg[binary] be mutually exclusive? You can install both and then choose your favorite implementation on runtime.

Mine is not an answer. I would like poetry install -E pgbinary -E pgc to fail. Also ["psycopg", "psycopg-binary"] is not the complete list of what psycopg[binary] installs, and I would not want to be the one to keep this list in sync

IMHO that is an answer with a compromise but still an answer.

What worked for me was using groups group as follows -
[tool.poetry.group.psycopgc.dependencies]
psycopg = { version = "^3.1.0", extras = ["c"],  optional = true}

[tool.poetry.group.psycopgb.dependencies]
psycopg = { version = "^3.1.0", extras = ["binary"],  optional = true}

omitting psycopg from the general dependencies of the project and installing it as so -
poetry install --with psycopgc --without psycopgb
Of course its not optimal, but a good workaround in my opinion.
